What is this foamy object under the hood?

What is the name of this spongy object under the hood of a 2017 Honda Civic?
It is located near the windshield on the driver's side and passenger side.  It looks like it would help support the hood when coming down.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

EPT or polyurethane foam.

These are seals. I believe they help control the air flow out from under the hood. It doesn't support the hood, but rather it gets squashed by the hood to help it seal.
